method is not supported for route login
The GET method is not supported for route login. Supported methods: POST.

I don't understand where the login happens here
Why doesn't my Kernel go further?
My Client
 async resend() {
        try {
            await $axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
            await $axios.post('/email/verification-notification')
                .then((resp) => {
                    this.message = resp.data.message
                })
        } catch (error) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors
        }
    },


I think some middleware is redirecting to route login, and your login is a post route. Not able to understand much more with this information. Post your login and email/verification-notification routes.

kris gjika - Thanks a lot

In your laravel app where you have defined route for the login,
Instead
Route::get('login', Logincontroller....)

You should have
Route:post('login', Logincontroller...)

